# vbscript how to convert minutes to a day, hours and minutes format

Tags: vbscript

Hi I have a report that uses `vbscript` to do my logic with my fields.

The report has a field that are the total minutes and has big values such: 1950 minutes, etc.

I need to update other field in order to convert those minutes to a readable format like 4 days 2 hours 30 minutes. My days are for 8 hours because is my labor day.

So 16 hours = 2 days and so on.

Right now my logic is this one:

```
 ' get the total minutes
total = sum(lateminutes)

' divide the minutes by 60 to get hours
hours = Int(total) / 60 

' get the division difference and convert it to minutes
minutes = Round((hours - Int(hours)) * 60)

' convert my hours to days by dividing into 8 (8 hours per day)
days = Int(hours) / 8 

if Int(days) > 0 then
text = Cstr(Int(days)) & " day(s)" & " "
end if

if Int(hours) > 0 then
text = text & Cstr(Int(hours)) & " hours" & " "
endif

if Int(minutes) > 0 then
text = text & minutes & " min"
endif

testfield.Text = text
```

> But I'm not getting the correct result, any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the larger units by integer division (), substract the minutes 'used' by the larger units from your input value. In code:

```
Option Explicit

Const cnMWD = 480 ' 8 * 60 mins in 8 hour working day
Const cnMWH =  60 ' 60 mins in 60 min working hour

Dim otp : otp = Array(0, "day(s)", 0, "hour(s)", 0, "mins")
Dim m, mm
For Each m In Array(59, 61, 479, 480, 485, 545, 2060)
    mm     = m
    otp(0) = m \ cnMWD
    m      = m - otp(0) * cnMWD
    otp(2) = m \ cnMWH
    m      = m - otp(2) * cnMWH
    otp(4) = m
    WScript.Echo mm, "=>", Join(otp)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 28798880.vbs
59 => 0 day(s) 0 hour(s) 59 mins
61 => 0 day(s) 1 hour(s) 1 mins
479 => 0 day(s) 7 hour(s) 59 mins
480 => 1 day(s) 0 hour(s) 0 mins
485 => 1 day(s) 0 hour(s) 5 mins
545 => 1 day(s) 1 hour(s) 5 mins
2060 => 4 day(s) 2 hour(s) 20 mins
```